# Getting records from Database using two parameters

Tags: vba, excel

I am having difficulties for 3 days now trying retrieving Data from sql Server using a stored procedure with two Parameters. I am keeping on getting the ERROR 3704. It is all about the recordset and I don't really kown further.

The funny thing is that this `vba code works without parameters.

```
Public Sub getRecords()

Dim con As ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim par As String
Dim WSP1 As Worksheet

Set con = New ADODB.Connection
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    Application.StatusBar = "Contacting SQL Server..."

    ' Remove any values in the cells where we want to put our Stored Procedure's results.

    Dim rngRange As Range
    Set rngRange = Range(Cells(20, 1), Cells(Rows.Count, 1)).EntireRow
    rngRange.ClearContents

    ' Log into our SQL Server, and run the Stored Procedure
    con.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;Data Source=myServer;Initial Catalog=myDataBase"
    cmd.ActiveConnection = con
    cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc

    cmd.CommandTimeout = 0

    'Set up the parameter for our Stored Procedure
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("Periode1", adVarChar, adParamInput, 10, Range("E9").Text)
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("Periode2", adVarChar, adParamInput, 10, Range("E11").Text)

    Application.StatusBar = "Running stored procedure..."
    cmd.CommandText = "spTest"
    Set rs = cmd.Execute(, , adCmdStoredProc)

    'Copy the results to cell B7 on the first Worksheet
    Set WSP1 = Tabelle2
    WSP1.Activate
    'If rs.EOF = False Then Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(Rows.Count, 1)).EntireRow

    If rs.EOF = False Then WSP1.Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set cmd = Nothing

    con.Close
    Set con = Nothing

    Application.StatusBar = "Data successfully updated."

End Sub
```

The Runtime Error is on this line:

```
If rs.EOF = False Then
```

Will appreciate a help or an alternative

Comment: since you do not qualify your `Range` object to a **specific** worksheet are you sure that the worksheet you think is active is *really* the active sheet and thus pulling the values you want into the parameters argument?

Comment: What does the SP look like?

Comment: Hi Scott. Yes it it pulling the right values if I do debug. The problem is with the recordset and I get no idea.

Comment: Hi Rory
The SP has two parameters
@Periode1 varchar ,@Periode2 varchar

Comment: @James - since you said the debug showed the right values, this may not make a different but try `Range("E11").Value2` instead of `.Text` (do this for both.

Comment: @Scott
It still produce the same Runtime error at the same spot.

My question why is it giving me an error at the spot?

Comment: @James -  I know. I had some thoughts that maybe the parameters values were not correct. However, that would have thrown an error at a different line.... How about try `If Not rs.EOF Then` or `If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then`

Comment: @ Scott 
The same error :)  I guess but not sure that it might have something to do with my connection string or?

Comment: @James Are you sure that the query it is returning data?, try with if rs.RecordCount > 0 Then ....

Answer (score 0):

Stored procedure should return table:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spTest

@Param1 AS INT,
@Param2 as INT
AS

BEGIN

  SELECT TOP 10 * FROM Test
  WHERE Param1=@Param1
  AND   Param2=@Param2
END
```

This error appears when you don’t return table by procedure but value